Calculate Linear and Log model increase in percentage
I have 2 regression tables for linear and log-log models.
Linear Model



Coefficient
Value




intercept
116.75


price
-7.63


advert
1.87



Log Model



Coefficient
Value




intercept
5.27


price
-0.55


advert
0.044



Below I have information for mean value for sales, advert and price.



Variables
Mean Value




Sales in '000
50


price
2


advert in $'000
7



Holding other variable constant, if increase 1% for adverts, in linear model it will be:
advert = 2
2 x 1/100 = 0.02
change in sales volume = 0.02 x 1.87 = 0.0374
Is the calculation above correct?
How will it be if 1 % increase for advert in log model then?

How does the log model look like in your case?

You mean the significance of the model itself?

No, I'm asking myself if the model looks like $y=s+c_1\log (p)+c_2\log (a)$ or $\log (y)=s+c_1\log (p)+c_2\log (a)$ or ...

I interpret your question is what is the corresponding change from the mean value.
The change of sales for the linear model is $3.74\%$ as you have shown.
For the log-log model.
$$S_0=cP^aA^b$$
$$S_1=cP^a(1.01A)^b=1.01^bS_0$$
can you simplify the following expression?
$$\frac{S_1-S_0}{S_0}\times 100\%$$

Can you insert the figures so i can get a better picture? Quite loss touch on log model

here $P$ is the price, $A$ is the advert, $a$ is the coefficient of price, $b$ is the coefficient of advert.
